# Emacs repeat the replace pattern - macro?

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp, text-editor, emacs24

I want to same kind of change in multiple lines.

For e.g. I want to enclose each line in the file with a table cell  element like this below.

```
  <td>
  <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header></div>
  </td>
```

I want the each line below to be enclosed with  like above.

```
  <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header></div>
  <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header></div>
  <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>D</header></div>
  <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>E</header></div>
```

How can we achieve this? As i understand we need to use macros, can you give pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `C-x (` `<td>` `C-e` `</td>` `C-n` `C-a` `C-x )` while at the beginning of the line.

That should create a macro that encloses the current line in a `<td>`, `</td>`. Now, do a `C-x e` as many times as you want to repeat it.

*Update* : The screencast which I've mentioned in the comments is up at http://emacsmovies.org/blog/2012/09/17/keyboard_macros/ in case you want to take a look.

Comment: Thanks. Emacs macros would save lot of typing effort and stay in the flow of doing things (instead of typing repeatedly).

Comment: And do `C-u 10` to repeat next command, for example recorded macro `C-x e`, ten (or chose your own number) times.

Comment: Note that you don't need to have the macro include `C-n` and `C-a` to move to the next line. Any macro that handles one line can be applied to a whole region using `M-x apply-macro-to-region-lines`.

Comment: Macros are going to be the subject of the next emacsmovies.org screencast.

Comment: You can keep repeating a macro after `C-x e` by hitting more `e`, e.g. `C-x e e e e e` will repeat the macro 5 times.